# Trying to understand whether a default true value should be provided to a prop or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this section in the react docs.

I couldn't figure out which example they are saying is good or bad to use and why exactly. Can someone please explain the recommendation. Thanks

```js
Props Default to “True”
If you pass no value for a prop, it defaults to true. These two JSX expressions are equivalent:

<MyTextBox autocomplete />

<MyTextBox autocomplete={true} />
In general, we don’t recommend using this because it can be confused with the ES6 object shorthand {foo} which is short for {foo: foo} rather than {foo: true}. This behavior is just there so that it matches the behavior of HTML.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that you should explicitly define `autocomplete={true}`.

Because the default ES6 object shorthand will automatically expand from `{autocomplete}` to `{autocomplete: autocomplete}`, by explicitly defining it as true, it wont get confused with `autocomplete=autocomplete` (The prop autocomplete equal to the variable autocomplete).

You can see how this may get confusing:

```js
var autocomplete = 'foo';

console.log({autocomplete});
```

Comment: Thanks, so you mean this could cause confusion if you had the variable autocomplete already defined in your code somewhere because the value of 'foo' could overwrite the value of 'true' which is what you intended?

Comment: The point is to avoid **confusion**...which is exactly what is happening now. Just stick with `autocomplete={true}` if you intend to set autocomplete equal to true.

Comment: @jobe At no point will the variable be overridden. The point is, when you see `<TextBox autocomplete />` someone may think that autocomplete is set to the variable autocomplete, but **it's not**. It's set to true. Explicitly defining `autocomplete={true}` completely removes this confusion.

Comment: Thanks I was asking because I was asked to do it without the explicit assignment and wanted to understand what React recommend, your explanation makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no generally accepted *recommendation* about this.

Personally speaking, I prefer the **second variant** because it is clarifying in an **explicit way** the value being passed to the `autocomplete` property.
I worked on projects where this explicit style was adopted as a team policy; conversely, I worked on projects where the **first style** was adopted,  with the motivation that this is the **more concise** style of the two (and the `true` default value was generally accepted and recognized by the team).

My advise is, as e.g. for indentation or formatting styles, to adhere to a team-shared policy, that represents the minimum possible cognitive effort for the team when reading code.